# How to obtain the access token in Teams?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I have developed a Sharepoint Web Part and now I want to use this component inside my Teams.

In this Web Part, I have obtained the access token using Msal library, but for any reason, It doesn't work in Teams.

```
   myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then((accessTokenResponse) => {
         // Acquire token silent success
         let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
```

I was trying to obtain the token using something like this, but it's not working:

```
    this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.teamsJs.authentication.authenticate({
              url: window.location.origin + "/tab-auth/simple-start",
              successCallback: (result) => {
                  alert(result.accessToken);
              },
              failureCallback: (reason) => {
                 alert("error");
              }
          });
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Can you please share what error are you getting while trying to authenticate. You can refer [these sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/tree/master/src/views/tab-auth) . Please have a look into [authentication in Ms Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad)

Comment: HI @Subhasish-MSFT, If I work with Msal in Teams, never pass through this function:  myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then((accessTokenResponse)

Comment: If I use microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: window.location.origin + "/tab-auth/simple-start",
    width: 600,
    height: 535,
    successCallback: function (result) {
        getUserProfile(result.accessToken);
    },
    failureCallback: function (reason) {
        handleAuthError(reason);
    }
});. How can I cast result.accessToken in TypeScript?